# Finding a closed form of this series: $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {n-\sqrt{n^2+1}\over\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am looking for
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {n - \sqrt{n^2 + 1}\over \sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$
I rewrite the expression and see that the terms of the series are negative

$${-1 \over n\sqrt{n(n+1)}+\sqrt{n(n+1)(n^2+1)}}$$
This is where I get stuck. I would appreciate any clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I suspect there is a typo in the given series.*

One has
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^N {n - \sqrt{n^2 \color{red}{-} 1}\over \sqrt{n(n+1)}}&=\sum_{n = 1}^N\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}-\frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\right)
\\\\&=\sum_{n = 1}^N\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}-\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right)
\\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{N}{N+1}}-0
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $N \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{n = 1}^\infty {n - \sqrt{n^2 \color{red}{-} 1}\over \sqrt{n(n+1)}}=1.
> $$